# Edit .dic file for removing slangs

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spell-checking, aspell

I am using a dictionary file to be used with Jazzy spell-checker. However recently it was discovered that the file contains several slang words, that need to be removed. using a new dictionary isn't an option. 
Could anyone suggest any program/api to find out all the slang words from the file and remove/replace them.

Comment: 1+ for the ironic title

Comment: This question is really off topic for SO but have a look at http://h3manth.com/content/introducing-slang-api